# OpenGL: Fish-eyes effect and how to avoid this

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to model the Solar System and I'm experiencing the Fish-eyes effects.

As you can see from the picture, the sun is at the centre, the Earth is translated 20 units to the x-axis and it doesn't look like a sphere anymore.

[image]

In `glm::lookAt` function, I set the field of view (is this FoVx?, I read from wiki, this is horizontal field of view so I think this is FoVx.) to be 80 degree, aspect ratio is `5.4f / 3.0f` (most of application set the aspect ratio to be 4/3 but if I use this ratio, these planets look exactly like an ellipse!).

So how can I solve this problem? As the Earth would be orbiting around the Sun, and it should be always be a sphere at any angle and distance of view. Maybe I haven't completely understand the perspective, view matrix etc. Really need some help.

Here is the code which I used to render the Sun and the Earth:

```
void renderSun(int i){
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_ID[0]);
    glUniform1i(texture_Location, 0);
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(90.0f, 5.4f / 3.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0, 30, 1),
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
    );

    /* Animations */
    GLfloat angle = (GLfloat) (i);
    //View = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(-2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    View = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    /* ******* */
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvpMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numsToDraw, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    glPopMatrix();
}


void renderEarth(int i){
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_ID[3]);
    glUniform1i(texture_Location, 0);
    //glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.f, 800.f, 0.f, 400.f, -5.f, 5.f );
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(80.0f, 5.4f / 3.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0, 30, 2),
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
    );

    /* Animations */
    GLfloat angle = (GLfloat) (i);
    View = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(30.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    //View = glm::scale(View, glm::vec3(4.0f, 5.0f, 4.0f));
    View = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    /* ******* */
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvpMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numsToDraw, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: 90 looks like a lot, pick what looks natural in your application (start from 45). Also a sphere isn't a sphere after perspective transformation, that's typical

Comment: The field of view parameter is for the vertical screen direction.If you want a correct projection, this value depends on the screen height and the distance to the observer. You can use typical values to determine this parameter.

Comment: Could you help me one more question: how I can change the line `glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(90.0f, 5.4f / 3.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);` to `glm::ortho` ? I tried: `glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)width,(float)height,0.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);` but there are nothing shown on the screen. Is this due to the way I calculate `gl_Position` in vertex shader?

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it and understand how glm::ortho works :)